# Getting input value with javascript when it's not part of the form?

Tags: javascript

I am dealing with two versions of a page. The first one has a search input field as part of a form, and I can get that value no problem with

```
document.getElementsByClassName('search-input')[0].value
```

i.e. this will update as it's being typed. On the other version of the page (which I have no control over) the input field is not part of a form, and now the above code doesn't work (the class of the input field is still "search input").

Here is the html where it's working fine:

```
<form action="search-landing.aspx" method="GET">
      <input class="search-input" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="City, State or Zip" name="location" required="">
      <button id="searchButton" tabindex="0" class="search-btn" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

And here is the code where it's not

```
<div class="search-box">
     <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="City, State or Zip">
</div>
```

Does anyone know why I'm having this issue? Is there a way around it (i.e. to grab a value from an input field that is NOT part of a form)?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure thats the only instance of the 'search-input' class on the page where its not working?  your specifying the first always with [0].  id try dumping that getElementsByTagName to console

Comment: When I do document.getElementsByClassName('search-input')[0] I get the correct inputfield back, but when I do .value it just gives me an empty string (even though I have typed stuff in). I don't have the ability to change the html code...

Comment: OK I'm a fool. Just tried document.getElementsByClassName('search-input')[1].value and sure enough there it was. They had two almost identical looking input fields, not sure why...thanks @Rooster and MazzCris

Comment: seems to work fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/300/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rooster correctly pointed out that I may have more than 1 input field of class "search-input". There were two identical fields, one hidden so document.getElementsByClassName('search-input')[1].value was the answer in this case